# Play sound in Chronometer after 30 seconds has passed

Tags: android, audio, chronometer, soundeffect

I have this stopwatch that needs to play a sound after 30, 45 and 60 seconds pass.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.random1);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/tele.ttf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bowman);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    player1 = MediaPlayer.create(Random1.this, R.raw.stopwatch1);
    player2 = MediaPlayer.create(Random1.this, R.raw.stopwatch2);
    player3 = MediaPlayer.create(Random1.this, R.raw.stopwatch3);
    player4 = MediaPlayer.create(Random1.this, R.raw.stopwatch4);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstartsw1);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstopsw1);
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bresetsw1);
    vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    start.setTypeface(tf);
    stop.setTypeface(tf);
    reset.setTypeface(tf);

    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bstartsw1:
        mChronometer.start();
        vib.vibrate(50);

        break;
    case R.id.bstopsw1:
        mChronometer.stop();
        vib.vibrate(50);

        break;
    case R.id.bresetsw1:
        mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        vib.vibrate(50);
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        break;
    }

    mChronometer
            .setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                    long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                            - chronometer.getBase();
                    if (elapsedTime > currentNeededTime1) {
                        player1.start();
                        currentNeededTime1 += currentNeededTime1 == 14500 ? 3600000
                                : 3600000;
                    } else if (elapsedTime > currentNeededTime2) {
                        player2.start();
                        currentNeededTime2 += currentNeededTime2 == 30000 ? 3600000
                                : 3600000;
                    } else if (elapsedTime > currentNeededTime3) {
                        player3.start();
                        currentNeededTime3 += currentNeededTime3 == 45000 ? 3600000
                                : 3600000;

                    } else if (elapsedTime > currentNeededTime4) {
                        player4.start();
                        currentNeededTime4 += currentNeededTime4 == 60000 ? 3600000
                                : 3600000;
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

}

Not the most famous solution, but its a solution.
In reset button i set the finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
so it reloads the activity and sound plays normaly on 15, 30, 45 and 60 secons as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `OnChronometerTickListener` on your chronometer.

Here is an example:

```
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer)
    {

    }
});
```

You can check the ellapsed time in `onChronometerTick` method

Comment: I have implemented it exactly this way and `onChronometerTick` is never called.